# What's the best way of handling a timed out login session for Ajax requests?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Using forms authentication, with a non ajax request the response code is a 302 redirect and the clients browser is redirected to the `account/logon` etc. default login page.

However if one is making an Ajax request and the login session has timed out, likewise it seems the ajax call thread handler is given a 302 redirect and it then requests the `account/logon` etc. page and returns it as the `responseXML` property of the `jqXHR` object.
Obviously such behaviour has unwanted results, whereby the returned login page is not a partial view one would typically request with an ajax call and includes the layout header, navigation etc. layout elements and my javascript then inserts this HTML into the target element, causing a full layout within a full layout effect.

I am currently thinking of solving this by simply checking on the server, on the `/account/logon` action method if the request is an ajax request and if so returning a partial view, which will be a logon form. This appears to more or less work, but I also can't seem to set the response code so as to help me differentiate between normal content data returned for an authenticated request and data for the logon partial view when session times out. I can probably do it in some hacky way, but I just wanted to know what's the correct/conventional way to approach this problem. Perhaps I should be using the textStatus property of the jqXHR to signal it's a logon form and not use the status code to do this, how does one set the value for the jqHXR.textStatus in ASP.NET anywhere?

Right now I am trying:

```
public ActionResult LogOn()
{
    bool isAjaxCall = string.Equals("XMLHttpRequest", Request.Headers["x-requested-with"], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    if (isAjaxCall) { Response.StatusCode = 409; return PartialView("LogOnForAjaxView"); }

    else return View();
}




$.post(path, function (data, textStatus, xhr) {

         if(xhr.status != 409)    $('#content-wrapper').html(data);

         else // Present the form html, overlay it over the page content etc.                 
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

In whatever server method your ajax is calling check to see if session is active and if not throw an exception. Handle this exception in the error callback of your ajax request javascript.

Comment: hmmm, I just applied an authorize flag to the entire controller,I am lazy like that. Will introducing this logic into the said action method still work if the entire controller is flagged with an [authorize] ?